# How to convert channel last keras model into channel first ONNX model

Tags: keras, onnx

I want to convert keras .h5 model into ONNX model. But my model is trained channel last and I want it channel first.
I found that there is an argument in `keras2onnx.convert_keras` called `channel_first_inputs` but couldn't find any example on how to use it on their [official site](https://github.com/onnx/keras-onnx/blob/master/README.md).

I am doing this step as a part of the process of converting my keras model into *.engine* model. Is there any other way to do so without the need to onnx intermediate step?.

---

Searching for the parameter name inside the keras2onnx code, I found the following usage

- In [Here](https://github.com/onnx/keras-onnx/blob/239908eefbba216c3f138364b14af31a8fd2b18b/applications/yolov3/yolov3.py): **channel_first_inputs=['input_1']**
- In [Here](https://github.com/onnx/keras-onnx/blob/17559f987ecce7ec40ab8a36a9596eb950f9b332/tests/test_layers.py): **channel_first_inputs=[model.input_names[0]]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `channel_first_inputs=['input_1']` and it worked fine.